# Google datastore stats

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am querying the __Stat_Kind__ kind. It does not return me entities
about kinds that currently exist in the datastore but it includes
entities about kinds that I had deleted more than a week ago.

I am not so much concerned about it returning me the non-existent
kinds - the doc does mention this scenario after all.

But I am concerned that it does not return me info about my current
kinds. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

---

To folks on the app engine team:

Also, on the dev server neither __Stat_Kind__ nor __Stat_Total__
return any entities. Which means I need to deploy my app to appspot
before I can test this behavior. It would be nice if the dev server
did return some basic info.

Thanks,
Keyur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datastore stats generally update daily, but sometimes less frequently.

The kinds don't exist on the dev_appserver, because they're populated by a process that runs in production only. Fair point, though - feel free to open a bug for it.

Comment: Today I can see my updates from yesterday. But yesterday it showed stats that were about a week old. So I guess your point on updates being sometimes less frequently applies. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Datastore statistics don't update immediately (they would be a performance drain if they updated on every write).  How recently did you create the entities that aren't showing up in stats?

Also, you may want to make sure that the stats entity you are fetching is the most recent one (see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f2e7568040c015ff?pli=1)).